# PowerShell Form sizing is different when run outside of ISE

Tags: winforms, powershell

I have created a PowerShell Forms application and it looks and runs great in ISE.  When I run it from the console, shortcut, or .ps1, the main form sizing is smaller and cuts off control elements.  None of the individual child form objects are shrunk in this manner.  This is not the issue with visual styles and an old looking Form.

If I manually edit the size: (`$form.Size = "1015,289"`) to (`$form.Size = "1030,310"`) for instance, the form size grows accordingly in both ISE and in `PowerShell.exe`.  I am struggling to understand why this would occur.

Keep in mind I am pretty new to Forms in PowerShell, so if it's obvious, I would greatly appreciate a kind response.  It seems a few others have this issue, but the question received no answers ([MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/56352ca7-3e6e-452a-a1c8-09ab65c07089/powershell-wpf-window-sizes-different-when-run-outside-of-ps-ise?forum=wpf)).

Comment: Consider providing an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) directly in your question.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I am going to need some help providing that.  It's a pretty simple script, but its very, very long.  It's currently about 1200-1300 lines, with functions for a number of different controls.  The script itself works perfectly fine, both in ISE and standard PowerShell.  The ONLY thing that is odd, is that Size in ISE doesn't equal Size in standard PowerShell.  I am not sure exactly what part of my script you would need to see to answer that.

Comment: This is exactly where the _M_ part - for _minimal_ comes in: whittle your script down to the smallest example that exhibits the symptom, and update your question with it - no guarantee of a personal response, but someone may be able to help you then.

Comment: To anyone that has this issue, it could be a combination of things.  I solved it for myself, but I had mixed results changing a variety of things.  I will note some of these below.  Certain things DO NOT work the same in ISE and regular PowerShell.

For instance:

Comment: If you have findings to share that you think are helpful to others, please post them as an answer (and optionally self-accept).

Comment: What solved my issue was changing the following:
'$form.Size'

to

 '$form.ClientSize'

and then adjusting the pixel counts to match the new sizing.  I don't understand why these differ or how - a much more advanced developer could probably explain it.  But if your are having the issue I was having, only .ClientSize seems to maintain the same sizing ratio between the two.

Comment: I was having CTRL+ENTER issues and then ran out of time editing my first response...

:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following:

```
$form.Size
```

to

```
$form.ClientSize
```

Re-adjust your form pixels as appropriate.