# Size Discrepancy: Powershell ISE vs Batch Launcher

Tags: wpf, windows, powershell, xaml

I have a XAML GUI that is created in Powershell using the XML Node Reader. All of my controls are exactly where I want them when I run the script in the ISE. I then created a batch file to launch it:

```
Powershell.exe -STA -File "C:\Scripts\Study App\Core.ps1"
```

After running the batch file, I notice that the GUI itself is larger than when in the ISE and as a result, a few of my buttons are misaligned. I also noticed this behavior when I right click the ps1 file and click Run with Powershell. **What is it about the ISE that results in a smaller window size and is there a way for me to combat this?**

There is an almost identical question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40518163/powershell-form-sizing-is-different-when-run-outside-of-ise) but there is a significant difference: My form is of type *System.Windows.Window* and doesn't have the needed properties that *System.Windows.Forms.Form* has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PowerShell ISE loads additional libraries that are not loaded when using straight PowerShell. I did a quick search and found this issue on another site:

[https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/56352ca7-3e6e-452a-a1c8-09ab65c07089/powershell-wpf-window-sizes-different-when-run-outside-of-ps-ise?forum=wpf][1]

It appears that the solution may be using SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight".

Comment: That didn't fix it. It's still off by 5 to 10 pixels.

Comment: From what I can see it may be a assembly that the ISE is loaded that Powershell doesn't load. `[appdomain]::currentdomain.getassemblies() | sort -property fullname | format-table fullname` will show you the assemblies being loaded in either the ISE or Powershell.

I did a quick check and just a plain Powershell window loads 25 assemblies while the ISE loads 47 assemblies...

Comment: What assemblies are you calling into your script?

Comment: System.Windows.Forms
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization
System.Drawing
PresentationFramework
WindowsBase
PresentationCore
But it should be irrelevant since those assemblies are loaded in the ISE as well as via Batch file.

Comment: The thing is that the ISE loads more assemblies than just running a poweshell script will run. ISE load 47 assemblies. Just running a plain powershell session only loads 25. So, if something looks different in the ISE versus right clicking and running a ps1 file in Powershell then you need to find what assembly is missing and add it to your script.

Comment: The ISE is loading PresentationCore, PresentationFramework, PresentationFramework.Aero2, PresentationFramework-SystemCore, PresentationFramework-SystemData, PresentationFramework-SystemXml, Windows.UI, and WindowsBase. A plain Powershell sessions does not load those assemblies.